# I am facing some shutdown issue

Tags: kernel, shutdown, default

I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 and my current version of kernel is 6.2.0 - 26 - generic and if I try to shut down my operating system it takes 20 to 30 minutes to shutdown and I go on bad it tell me its because of my kernel current version and I want to change this default to my desire on stable karna so provide me stable kernel for my operating system

Comment: After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`. For more `journalctl` help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).